# Medir desempenho de acesso ao banco de dados SQLite do Android

Tags: android, sqlite, desempenho

Boa tarde,

Como posso medir o desempenho de acesso a banco de dados SQLite do Android?  Mais especificamente inserção e seleção no banco.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar mocks (dados de exemplos para entrada ou saida) no banco de dados SQLite e no App.

Suponho que vc já esteja utilizando **os melhores pattern para performance** do Android, com isso a cada inicio de requisição você pode inserir um **LOG** e no listener que recebe o resultado você coloca outro **LOG** indicando o fim da execução da SQL.

Exemplo, se estiver usando **AsyncTask**

```
private class SQLTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     Log.e(TAG,"inicio");
     //sua consulta SQL
     return totalSize;
 }


 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     Log.e(TAG,"fim");

 }
}
```

Com isso você vai saber quanto tempo está durando um comando SQL, você pode monitorar também usando o **Android Studio** na aba **Android Monitor** o uso da **CPU** e **memoria** da aplicação.

De qualquer forma tem outros N metodos de se fazer isso, tudo vai depender de como e quão detalhado você quer esse monitoramento